# How to fix game freeze when loading prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game where the player flies an aircraft. When they crash, it explodes.
In test, when the aircraft crashes, the game freezes for a solid 2-3 seconds before the respawn screen appears and the explosion is played. Heres my code:

```
    public void DestroyAircraft()
    {
        
        GameObject BrokenAircraft = ObjectPool.SharedInstance.GetPooledObject();
        if(BrokenAircraft != null)
        {
            BrokenAircraft.transform.position = Aircraft.transform.position;
            BrokenAircraft.transform.rotation = Aircraft.transform.rotation;
            BrokenAircraft.SetActive(true);
            if(explosion != null)
            {
                GameObject explosionFX = Instantiate(explosion, transform.position + explosionOffset, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                Destroy(explosionFX, 5);
                RespawnPoint.GetComponent<Spawn>().RespawnScreen.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        Aircraft.SetActive(false);
        
        foreach(Transform t in BrokenAircraft.transform)
        {
            var rb = t.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        
            if(rb != null)
            {
                rb.AddExplosionForce(Random.Range(minExplode, maxExplode), transform.position, radius);
            }
            
            Destroy(t.gameObject, DestroyDelay);
        }
        
    }
```

Ive tried removing the explosion particles to see if that was the issue, its not.

Comment: If you have issues with the performance - use the profiler to find the actual reason. Then you'll be able to resolve the issue or ask something more concrete =)

Comment: Ive used the profiler. There is no spikes at all when the player dies.

Comment: If there is no spike - there is no freeze. It is simple.

Comment: Maybe it's related with your code logic, your prefab object or respawn screen. Not clear at all. Please give more detailed information to us for possible factor of problem..

Comment: @Morion I don't understand how you can say that lol. The game freezes when the player crashed. Nothing else to it. The reason I made the post is because I don't understand why there is a freeze because there are no spikes in profiler.

Comment: @BerkAskin basically what the code does is I have created an object pool with the destroyed aircraft stored. The code first sets the aircrafts position and rotation to identical to the players aircraft, then it shows the aircraft. Then it shows the respawn screen, then destroys the old aircraft (not destroyed one). I will test changing around the order of this to destroy the old one first, but other then that. IDK why it freezes. It is a mobile game, and I have an APK download for the game that you could test to see it for yourself if you'd like.

Comment: @GhostPlays74 I can say that because it is true. I rather believe that you have several options disabled in your profiler view than there is no spike during the game freeze.

Comment: @Morion I dont know what else to tell you. There is no spike in the profiler, but the game freezes. The first thing I did when I got the problem was check the profiler, but since there was no spike, I made the post. And no I dont have "several options disabled in the profiler" , Im not dumb dude, I know how to use the profiler, and I know where to look for performace issues within it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in lots of print () to see which line of code gets stuck.
For example, in each line of code you can enter print (Time.time).
The console will show you many messages with the times, but some of them will have a much larger difference of a few tenths of a second.
The line with the greatest difference between the printed times will be the one that slows down the game.